# LINQ and EF with string.StartWith(char c)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've got a problem with a search mechanic like as we sometime see on site. I've a big list of says, person. The way to filter a a list of : "#, A, B, C, D, E, [...]".

The problèm I have its when i execute de query with EF, an error pop out. Here's is my code.

Code :

```
var query = from  p in m_context.Persons
            where char.IsDigit(p.Name, 0)
            select a;
```

The error says that it's impossible to convert it into a valid expression against the database. So, is there anyway to do it?

Thanks guy.

UPDATE =======================

Here's my error.

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[Char](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Char], Char)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

```
var query = m_context.Persons.Where("substring(it.Name, 1, 1) in MULTISET('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')");
```

references:

[Entity SQL Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738683.aspx)